# How can I show this equation is less than or equal to $\pi$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have that $$ \left|\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2+z^2}\right| $$
where $\gamma$ is upper half of unit circle

I know that $$\gamma(t) = e^{it}$$
and therefore $$\gamma(t) = e^{it}$$

and as $$ \left|\int_\gamma f(z)\ \mathrm{d}z\right| = \left|\int_a^b f\big(\gamma(t)\big)\gamma'(t)\ \mathrm{d}t\right| $$

I know the originally equation is equal to $$\left|\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{2 + (e^{it})^2}ie^{it}\ \mathrm{d}t\right|$$

how could I show this is $\displaystyle\left|\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{2 + (e^{it})^2}\cdot ie^{it}\ \mathrm{d}t\right|\le \pi$

Comment: I think that when you write "equation", you should rather write "expression".

Comment: Your latest edit, in which you have erased the original problem, has the effect of making both your post and the answer of @Gregory nonsensical. I have therefore rolled back to the previous edit.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \bigg | \int_0^\pi \frac{i e^{i\theta} d \theta}{2 + e^{2i\theta}} \bigg | \le   \int_0^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{|2 + e^{2i \theta}|} \le \pi $$
Where we have written $z = e^{i\theta}$ and the last inequality follows from noting that $|2+e^{2i\theta}| \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just find an anti-derivative and use the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note, that u-substitution of $u=e^{i\theta}$ and $du=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$, would be helpful.

$$\int_0^\pi \frac{ie^{i\theta}}{2+e^{2i\theta}}d\theta=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}\frac{du}{2+u^2} = \left.\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(u/\sqrt{2})\right|_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi} = \left.\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(e^{i\theta}/\sqrt{2})\right|_0^\pi$$ $$= \frac{1}{2}\left(\tan^{-1}(-1/\sqrt{2})-\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{2})\right) = -0.615479708670387...$$